# How to join tables without identifiers?

Tags: mysql, join

For school I have to do this:

Query what salary scale an employee belongs to displaying these columns:

```
s_schaal.schaal, werknemer.name, werknemer.salaris
```

But there are no identifiers between the tables. All I have is a bottom line and upper line column (s_schaal.ondergens & s_schaal.bovengrens).

What MySQL query can I use to compare and join this data?

[image: ERD]

Comment: Any columns can be used in a `JOIN..ON`.  Indexed columns are better, for performance.  `FOREIGN KEYs` are not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured that joining these tables would not bring a solution. I solved it doing this:

```
SELECT S.schaal, W.wnr, W.wnaam, W.salaris FROM Werknemer W, S_schaal S 
WHERE W.salaris >= S.ondergrens && W.salaris <= S.bovengrens;
```

Comment: This is a join, without a `JOIN`.

Comment: I also discovered that, when using the ON clause in a join, you don't have to make the PK+FK comparison. You can also make it like this:

ON  W.salaris <= S.bovengrens AND W.salaris >= S.ondergrens

Comment: Right. Or: `ON w.salars BETWEEN s.ondergrens AND s.bovengrens`